# JSP insert data into MYSQL database

Tags: sql, database, jsp, insert

So I'm working on my JSP homework and what I'm trying to do is make the user enter a 
username and password which will then be added to my SQL database. I've been searching
through google for like 3 hours now trying different methods but so far no success. 
so far the closest I got was something very simple such as

```
"INSERT into database_name (username, password) VALUE = (${'param.rusername'}, ${'rpassword})"
```

Anyway I played around with a few different methods and this is how my JSP page looks now.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 

<sql:setDataSource scope="application"
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_schema"
user="root"
password="******"
/> 

<c:choose>
<c:when test="${empty param.rusername && empty param.rpassword}">
    <jsp:forward page="newUser.jsp" />     
</c:when>
</c:choose>                             

<html>
<body>
    <h1>Registration Complete</h1>
    <a href="index.jsp">Return to login</A>

    <%

    String username = request.getParameter("rusername");
    String password = request.getParameter("rpassword");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_schema", "root", "*****");

    Statement st = con.createStatement();

    String sql = ("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('password' + 'username')");
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
    con.close();

    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this.

If you must, read about JSTL `<sql>` tags; they'll make this problem easier to handle.  Scriptlet code should be avoided at all costs.